whis is code segfaulting only outside of gdb
I have some code performing relatively simple operations
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <curses.h>

char map[3600] = {
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
};
int getblock(int x,int y)
{
    

    
    return(map[x + 80 * y]);
}
int colread(char chr)
{
    switch(chr)
    {
        case 'k':
            return(COLOR_BLACK);
            break;
        case 'r':
            return(COLOR_RED);
            break;
        case 'g':
            return(COLOR_GREEN);
            break;
        case 'y':
            return(COLOR_YELLOW);
            break;
        case 'b':
            return(COLOR_BLUE);
            break;
        case 'm':
            return(COLOR_MAGENTA);
            break;
        case 'c':
            return(COLOR_MAGENTA);
            break;
        case 'w':
            return(COLOR_WHITE);
            break;

    }
        
}
void colinit()
{
    init_pair(0,COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(1,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(3,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_YELLOW);
    init_pair(26,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_BLUE);
}
void colman(char bg,char fg)
{
    int bgint = colread(bg);
    int fgint = colread(fg);
    if(bgint == 0 && fgint == 1)
    {
        attrset(0);
        attron(A_BOLD);
    }
    else
    {
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(bgint*8+fgint));
    }
    
}
void pixrender(int x,int y){/*oh god please no*/
addstr("rendered pixel");refresh();
char coord[3];
sprintf(coord,"%d",x);
addstr("(");
addstr(coord);
addstr(",");
sprintf(coord,"%d",y);
addstr(coord);
addstr(")");
/*

b blue
r red
w white
k black
blue for blocks, white for spikes
*/
char fku = 'f';
char spritesheet[144] = {
//         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1
/*empty */' ','x','n','v','d','b',' ',' ','-','_','[',']',
/*block */'*','X',fku,'V','d','b',' ',' ',fku,fku,'[',']',
/*spup  */'^','A','M','N','&','&',' ',' ','A',fku,'P','9',
/*spdwn */'Y',fku,'<','<','<','Z',' ',' ',fku,fku,fku,fku,
/*splft */'9','9','<','<','<','Z',' ',' ','<','<','<',fku,
/*sprht */'P','P','>','>','Z','>',' ',' ','>','>',fku,'>',
/*lava  */' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
/*ice   */' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
/*owup  */'~','~',fku,'T','Z','Z',' ',' ','~',fku,'[',']',
/*owdown*/'-','x','7','v','z','z',' ',' ','-','=','[',']',
/*owleft*/'[','[','9','Y','<','<',' ',' ','[','L','[','|',
/*owrht */']','h','R','j','>','>',' ',' ','[',']','|',']'
};
char bgsheet[144] = {
//         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1
/*empty */'k','b','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*block */'b','b',fku,'k','k','k','k','k',fku,fku,'k','k',
/*spup  */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*spdwn */'k',fku,'k','k','k','k','k','k',fku,fku,fku,fku,
/*splft */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',fku,
/*sprht */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',fku,'k',
/*lava  */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*ice   */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*owup  */'k','k',fku,'k','k','k','k','k','k',fku,'k','k',
/*owdown*/'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*owleft*/'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
/*owrht */'k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k',
};
char fgsheet[144] = {
//         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1
/*empty */'k','b','w','w','w','w',' ',' ','y','y','y','y',
/*block */'b','b',fku,'w','w','w',' ',' ',fku,fku,'y','y',
/*spup  */'w','w','w','w','w','w',' ',' ','y',fku,'y','y',
/*spdwn */'w',fku,'w','w','w','w',' ',' ',fku,fku,fku,fku,
/*splft */'w','w','w','w','w','w',' ',' ','y','y','y',fku,
/*sprht */'w','w','w','w','w','w',' ',' ','y','y',fku,'y',
/*lava  */' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
/*ice   */' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
/*owup  */'y','y',fku,'y','y','y',' ',' ','y',fku,'y','y',
/*owdown*/'y','y','y','y','y','y',' ',' ','-','y','y','y',
/*owleft*/'y','[','y','Y','y','y',' ',' ','y','y','y','y',
/*owrht */'y','h','y','y','y','y',' ',' ','y','y','y','y'
};
//segfault before here
int pos = getblock(x,2*y) + 12 * getblock(x,2*y+1);

colman(bgsheet[pos],fgsheet[pos]);
char cstr[2] = "\0";
cstr[0] = spritesheet[pos];
attron(A_BOLD);//why does this have to be here

addstr(cstr);
}
void render()
{
    int y = 24;
    int x;
    while (y >= 0)
    {
        x = 0;
        while(x < 80)
        {
            pixrender(x,y);
            x++;
        }
        if (y > 0)
        {
            addstr("\n");
        }
        y-=1;
    }
    clear();
    refresh();
        
}

void game()
{

    colinit();
    while (true)
    {
        render();

    }
}
int main()
{
    
    initscr();

    
    start_color();
    attron(A_BOLD);
    game();
    endwin();
    return(0);

}


and it works...but only in gdb, when running the same a.out outside of gdb, it crashes due to a segfault, does anyone know what sort of interaction could cause this (or if its some specific code related issue), the most relevant thing I could find was https://www.reddit.com/r/cprogramming/comments/18k3o01/issue_with_segfault_when_running_code_outside_of/ but that it doesnt seem like there would be any latent memory issues, there also isnt any database stuff so there shouldnt be anything with fread, could it be an undefined behaviour of some sort?

This is way too much code for anyone to scan here. When you debug the core file after the crash, what line does it say the segfault is on?

fptr = fopen(file,"rb"); but no check that it opened the file. This may be system specific, if the file does exist but is not on a current path. It's de rigueur to go if(fptr == NULL) ...

Opening and closing the file for every character is a horrible way to read a file. Why not just open it once and read bytes sequentially with fgetc()?

You need to reduce this to a [mre] with just enough code to reproduce the problem. We can't debug an 800-line program by eye.

"only outside of gdb" ... hmmm, uninitialized var? try running under valgrind.

There are at leat 2 occasions where you use == instead of = , such as inputptr->ydir == inputptr->prevydir;

it segfaults in valgrind when valgrind --leak-check=full is run

You also have maddieptr->xspeed + 1; and at least one more similar example of sloppy coding. Please deal with all the compiler warnings, before you go any further. Save yourself a lot of time.

cstr[0] = spritesheet[pos]; <- pos gets waaay out of bounds. I caught it at 1151 and the array is 144 long. Hint: Compile with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined and it'll tell you on what line it finds problems

... and if I run it in gdb i get a different value (-1332). If I run it without both gdb and sanitizers, it crashes even before reaching the point in the code I pointed out. Investigating the core file is probably the best bet.

I'm not sure how pos is supposed to go out of bounds? I mean its getblock(x,2*y) + 12 * getblock(x,2*y+1); and getblock never returns a value higher than 1

@user20695956 You can't argue against facts. It could be because of an uninitialized variable being read or some other undefined behavior elsewhere in your program.

Investigating the corefile: #0  0x0000000000401341 in getblock (x=16, y=49) at onlyingdb.c:101 101 return(map[x + 80 * y]); - and x + 80 * y is 3936 which is waaay out of bounds too since map is only 3600.

Conclusion: Learning how to make use of corefiles and sanitizers gets you closer to finding the problem.

Try to run the code in GDB with set disable-randomization off.
